# error: no such partion grub rescue>

Tags: boot, windows

I have windows 8. I can't get to boot menu and I have formatted partition which had Ubuntu on it.

- ***I need to get to windows.***

Can any one please help using the GRUB prompt as I have tried all other methods?

Comment: Are you trying to get the Ubuntu partition back?

Comment: If you formatted the partition where Ubuntu was located, and didn't created a separated `/boot` partition, it is almost sure you blew up your system. The only solution is reinstalling Ubuntu using a LiveUSB/CD.

Comment: there wasn't much in Ubuntu  i just installed it

Comment: there is worst part to it.. i can,t even go to boot menu as soon as i start computer even after pressing function keys it directs to grub prompt so i think only way to solve is to command .. can any one tell me the commands to get into windows

Comment: i had separate partition for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, if you formatted the partition that contained the MBR, then you won't be able to access your Windows System, because the place where the information about loading OSs has been swept away.

Since it seems that you are not longer interested in having Ubuntu in your machine, you'll need to use your Windows Repair CD, in order to restore your MBR properly.

Comment: i have formatted just the part which had ubuntu

Comment: there is worst part to it.. i can,t even go to boot menu as soon as i start computer even after pressing function keys it directs to grub prompt so i think only way to solve is to command .. can any one tell me the commands to get into windows